# SQL query doesn't work on a specific day

Tags: mysql, sql, time, timestamp

I have a weird problem in mysql!
my query is

```
SELECT * FROM aa WHERE problemTime>= '2016/03/20' AND problemTime<= '2016/04/20'
```

the result of this query is nothing , but when I change the first time to 2016/03/19 or 2016/03/21 I have the following result!  I mean these queries

```
SELECT * FROM aa WHERE problemTime>= '2016/03/21' AND problemTime<= '2016/04/20'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM aa WHERE problemTime>= '2016/03/19' AND problemTime<= '2016/04/20'
```

the result in both time ( 19th and 21th) is

[image]

but when I use 20th the result is noting

my main table is

[image]

I change the format of time from  2016/03/20 to 2016-03-20 ( I mean change / to - ) but it doesn't have change too!

whats the problem?

Comment: Kindly share table data in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really be running a query like this if your problemTime column is datetime type:

```
SELECT * FROM aa 
WHERE    
  problemTime>= str_to_date('2016/03/20', '%Y/%m/%d') AND 
  problemTime <= str_to_date('2016/04/20', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Don't rely on implicit conversions between string and date.. leave your table data alone and ensure you explicitly convert your where clause parameters to the same data type as in the table. Also remember that a date "without" a time is actually midnight on the day in question, and midnight is like zero, it's the first thing that happens on any given day. A time of 6am on a given date, is after midnight, so a query that asks for dates less than or equal to midnight on a particular date means the 6am date will be excluded

This is general good DB practice; do not convert table data where possible, because it can cause huge performance hits and wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Your column "problemTime" have date with time. Do not convert table data, change your where clause (add time).

```
SELECT * FROM aa WHERE problemTime>= '2016/03/20 00:00:00' AND problemTime<= '2016/04/20 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this as per SQl Server.

```
 SELECT * FROM aa 
 WHERe  cast(problemTime AS date)  between  '2016/03/21' AND '2016/04/20'
```

Comment: This question is not about sqlserver. Do not convert table data to suit your where clause, convert your where clause to suit your table. Definitely do not convert table data from one type to another type, and then rely on an implicit conversion to string to match your where clause

Comment: @Caius,  the where clause data convert is required as user want data within dates without including time.

Comment: You missed my point. If his table has a million rows, your query will force conversion of a million items of data, and also mean any index on this column will not work. Never convert table data, always convert the parameters in your where clause. Your parameters are strings `'2016/03/21' and '2016/04/20'` it is these you should be putting effort into converting so that they match the data type of the data in the table, as then that's just 2 things DB has to convert to date when query is compiled, not convert a million dates when query is running..

Comment: @Caius, The user passing parameters only with dates as per his requirements for date range. But the table Column is in Datetime datatype. So we need to cast the Datetime in Date . I agree that it will effect performance. Is there any other way ?